# Divided Among Groups

Tags: word-meaning

Could there be an error here:

> [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Africa)
>   About 80 percent of South Africans are of black African ancestry, ***divided among a variety of ethnic groups*** speaking different Bantu languages, nine of which have official status.

The use of "*divided*" seems to suggest that some external agent divided 80% of the south africans into ethnic groups.  Yet, it is the different ethnicity that cause the existence of such different groups.   Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: You're simply mistaken in assuming ***divided*** here implies some external "agent" coming in and "separating" the different ethnic groups. Think of it as meaning *which could be split into different categories, should anyone wish to do so*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But I cannot find such a sense in many online dictionaries.

Comment: True. And I've upvoted the answer explicitly confirming the intended sense. But I assume it's obvious to you that no "sentient" controller stepped in and split these people into different ethnicities. Which in and of itself means your "agent" interpretation can't be the right one. I can't say whether the *right* interpretation is "obvious" to you, but the *wrong* one is easily identified as such.

Answer (score 4):

This sentence is not using "divided" to describe anything that happened to the people; it is using "divided" to describe the way in which you could, if you chose, categorize the people.

Another way to put this sentence might be:

> About 80 percent of South Africans are of black African ancestry.
>
> These South Africans of black African ancestry belong to a variety of ethnic groups.

You are right that it is their ethnicity that divides these black South Africans. This sentence is recognizing this division; it does not, in English, imply that there is some agent or force sorting the people into ethnic groups.

Answer (score 1):

> About 80 percent of South Africans are of black African ancestry, divided among a variety of ethnic groups speaking different Bantu languages, nine of which have official status.

This is a long sentence. For your better understanding let's analyze and split the sentence -

```
1. `About 80 percent of South Africans are of black African ancestry.`

2. `This 80 percent of South Africans is divided among a variety of ethnic groups.`

3. `Those ethnic groups are speaking different Bantu languages, nine of which have official status.`
```

Now I have split the long sentences into small sentences.

I think you have problem with the second sentence.

Let's consider this sentence - *After the quarrel our family is divided into two*

Like sentence #2, the above sentence also doesn't bother about the "agent". If you can understand the above sentence you can understand sentence #2.

Does it make sense? Please let me know.

Comment: I'd say your second sentence should be: "This eighty percent is divided among a variety of ethnic groups."

Comment: @Jim Thanks Jim, for correcting me. You are absolutely correct. Let me edit my post.

Comment: You've broken down the sentence well, but I don't think OP's confusion was about the grammar--just about whether the word "divided" implied some external agent doing the dividing. So everything you've said is right, but I don't think it really answers the question.

Comment: @Tiercelet Actually I didn't directly answered OP's question. What I did is narrowed down his confusion by splitting the sentences, and then provided another sentence that is almost similar to the sentence that OP has problem with. I asked to consider both the sentences and reply back what OP thinks about them. This way I thought to clarify OP's doubt.